# vlc player screen capturing

Tags: screen, screen-scraping, vlc

If I turn on the outputmode "directx video-output" in vlc video I'm not able to make a screenshot (without getting a black image).

So 2 questions:
1.) Is there any solution to capture the image without changing the settings in vlc-player?
2.) If not, how can i get this effect for my application using c# (prevered) or c++?

Thanks for your help!
I'm sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0):

Use the menu item Video --> snapshot

Saves an image under "my images".  Very handy.

Comment: I know the menu item...
I want to create a application, where it is not possible to make a screenshot. Like in vlc player with the above settings on... for me it is not possible to make a screenshot with an external software